# Java JSP Tomcat доступ по ip

Tags: java, веб-программирование, jsp, tomcat

Запускаю томкет, деплоится туда варник и через localhost могу зайти. Как сделать, чтобы я попадал на страничку по внутреннему айпишнику компа и с других устройств сети тоже. В коннекторе прописывание adress не помогает...

Comment: Проверьте фаервол

Comment: фаервол вырублен

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего сеть объявлена как общественная.
Файрволл врубить; прописать шлюз, если не прописан; сеть сделать частной.